# Injecting the IServiceProvider for the current request scope

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, service-provider

In an ASP.NET Core 6 app, adding `IServiceProvider` to the service collection in this way allows injection of a scoped provider:

```
services.AddScoped(sp => sp);
```

But is it *the* scoped provider for the current request? In other words, is it guaranteed to provide the same instances of scoped dependencies that may have been injected elsewhere in the request?

XY: Method boundary callbacks are added to the service collection at startup. I'm injecting a service provider rather than the callbacks for two reasons: to break potential circular dependencies; and to avoid instantiating callbacks for all methods when only one method is being called.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you don't need to register service provider explicitly, it should be available without any extra registrations.

Second of all resolving `IServiceProvider` from the scope, at least ATM (.NET 6)  not only returns the same scoped provider, but the same instance:

```cs
var services = new ServiceCollection();
services.AddScoped<MyScopedDep>();
var serviceProvider = services.BuildServiceProvider();
using var serviceScope = serviceProvider.CreateScope();
var providerResolvedFromScope = serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IServiceProvider>();
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(serviceScope.ServiceProvider, providerResolvedFromScope)); // prints "True"
Console.WriteLine(object.ReferenceEquals(serviceScope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<MyScopedDep>(), providerResolvedFromScope.GetRequiredService<MyScopedDep>())); // prints "True"
```

And from the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/extensions/dependency-injection#scope-scenarios):

> For example, if you resolve services from a scope, and any of those services take an `IServiceProvider`, it'll be a scoped instance.